# Node/Expressjs: Stop Posting The User Image If user email already exist

Tags: node.js, api, express, validation, multer

I have made an API for the user registration and have validated it with a unique email and name. But the issue is the API runs perfect and don't post, new user, if the user has the same email or name but the middleware of the image runs but I want that image should upload when all validations clear. Here is the code.

```
/ Making The Storage using Multer 
 var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) { cb(null, './UserImages') },
   filename: function (req, file, cb) { cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname) }
 })
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
 })
 // Making The Storage using Multer 

 // Posting Users to the Db With Collection Name UserCluster
 Router.post('/RegisterUser',upload.single('UserImage'), (req, res,) => {

//1 Manual Api for testing Uniqueness of Data.
// RegisterUserModel.findOne({ $or: [{ Name: req.body.name }, { Email: req.body.email }] }).then(UserExist => {
//     console.log(UserExist);
//     if (UserExist) {
//         if (UserExist.Email==req.body.email) {
//             res.json({
//                 Message: 'User Already Exists With This Email',
//                 Data: null
//             });
//         }
//         else if(UserExist.Name==req.body.name){
//             res.json({
//                 Message: 'User Already Exists With This UserName',
//                 Data: null
//             });
//         }
//         else{
//             res.json({
//                 Message: 'User Already Exists With This UserName and Email',
//                 Data: null
//             });
//         }
//     }
//     else {
//         const _RegisterUser = new RegisterUserModel({
//             Name: req.body.name,
//             Email: req.body.email,
//             Mobile: req.body.mobile,
//             Password: req.body.password,
//             ImageUrl: req.file.filename,
//             ImageName: req.file.originalname,
//             ImageMimeType: req.file.mimetype,
//             Address: req.body.address
//         });
//         _RegisterUser
//             .save()
//             .then(result => {
//                 res.json({
//                     Message: "User Register Successfully",
//                     Data: result
//                 })
//             })
//             .catch(err => {
//                 res.json({
//                     Error: err.message,

//                 })
//             });
//     }
// })

const _RegisterUser = new UserCluster({
    Name: req.body.name,
    Email: req.body.email,
    Mobile: req.body.mobile,
    Password: req.body.password,
    ImageUrl: req.file.filename,
    ImageName: req.file.originalname,
    ImageMimeType: req.file.mimetype,
    Address: req.body.address
});
_RegisterUser
    .save()
    .then(result => {
        res.json({
            Message: "User Register Successfully",
            Data: result
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.json({
            Error: err.message,
            ErrorObject:err,
            Data:null,
            

        })
    });
```

});

Simple: My question is that the image should upload when all validation is clear. if not the image should not be uploaded. Please help me Thanks.

Comment: The comment are of the code  is for me as i am using the mongoose property unique:true on my schema

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tried it but as i am executing this code

```
        const _RegisterUser = new UserCluster({
            Name: req.body.name,
            Email: req.body.email,
            Mobile: req.body.mobile,
            Password: req.body.password,
            ImageUrl: req.file.filename,
            ImageName: req.file.originalname,
            ImageMimeType: req.file.mimetype,
            Address: req.body.address
         });
```

i got the error that ERROR:Cannot read property 'filename' and it will come because multer middler ware execeutes later

Comment: You can append imageUrl later if validation succeeds. If you use multer first, you will upload image to the server, and if validation failed you still have a useless image on your server and you can not rollback. So use validation first, then create user, then upload image and update the imageURL

Comment: Sir can you give me a snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
Router.post('/RegisterUser', uploadFunction, (req, res) => {
   ...
});
```

When you use the order like this, upload function will be executed first, no matter if you make some validation in your anonymous function.

You should swap the order and use `next()` if validation succeed.

```
Router.post('/RegisterUser', (req, res) => {
   ...
   if(validated) next(); // to go on next function (uploadFunction)
}, uploadFunction);
```

Comment: SIr Validation is coming from Mongoose Schema property unique:true

Comment: You can make validation if user already exist in separate function and call it first.